# savings records to activerecord from import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, paperclip

i have recently added an import option to my RoR project which seems to be uploading the file, and store this file into the db successfully, though when it attempts to create the new users and save them i am getting the following errors

```
Started GET "/imports/13/proc" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-11 02:52:00 +1000
Processing by ImportsController#proc_csv as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"13"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Import Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "imports".* FROM "imports" WHERE "imports"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "13"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'paul.mcguane1@westnet.com.au' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'compact721@***.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'paul.****@me.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'duncansingleton@****.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.4ms)  UPDATE "imports" SET "processed" = 4, "updated_at" = '2012-07-10 16:52:01.146297' WHERE "imports"."id" = 13
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
   (3.5ms)  commit transaction
```

this is the code i have in my imports controller

```
def new_user(line)
    params = Hash.new
    params[:user] = Hash.new
    params[:user]["email"] = line[0]
    params[:user]["gender"] = "male"
    params[:user]["password"] = "abc231"
    params[:user]["first_name"] = line[1]
    params[:user]["last_name"] = line[3]
    user = User.new(params[:user])
    user.save
  end


def proc_csv
    @import = Import.find(params[:id])
    lines = parse_csv_file(@import.csv.path)
    lines.shift #comment this line out if your CSV file doesn't contain a header row
    if lines.size > 0
      @import.processed = lines.size
      lines.each do |line|
        case @import.datatype
          when "releases"
            new_user(line)
            flash[:notice] = "Saving data processing was successful."
        end
      end
      @import.save
      flash[:notice] = "CSV data processing was successful."
      redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @import.id
    else
      flash[:error] = "CSV data processing failed."
      render :action => "show", :id => @import.id
    end
  end

  private

  def parse_csv_file(path_to_csv)
    lines = []

    #if not installed run, sudo gem install fastercsv
    #http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/
    require 'csv'

    CSV.foreach(path_to_csv) do |row|
      lines << row
    end
    lines
  end
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :admin, :manager
  attr_accessible :provider, :uid
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  belongs_to :team
  has_many :availabilities
  attr_accessible :last_name, :first_name, :jersey, :dob, :gender, :position, :team_id, :mobile, :state, :city, :postcode



  GENDER_TYPES = [:Male, :Female]
  STATE_TYPES = [:ACT, :VIC, :QLD, :NSW, :TAS, :NT, :WA, :SA]

  validates :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :presence => true
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i, :message => "isn't a valid email address"
  validates_format_of :mobile, :with => /^(?:\+?61|0)4(?:[01]\d{3}|(?:2[1-9]|3[0-57-9]|4[7-9]|5[0-35-9]|6[679]|7[078]|8[178]|9[7-9])\d{2}|(?:20[2-9]|444|68[3-9]|79[01]|820|901)\d|(?:200[01]|2010|8984))\d{4}$/, :message => "isn't a valid mobile number", :allow_blank => true
  validates_format_of :postcode, :with => /^[0-9]{4}/, :message => "isn't a valid Australian postcode", :allow_blank => true
```

rails console message

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > params = {
1.9.3p194 :002 >                :user => {
1.9.3p194 :003 >                          :gender => "male",
1.9.3p194 :004 >                       :last_name => "paul",
1.9.3p194 :005 >                        :password => "abc231",
1.9.3p194 :006 >                      :first_name => "mcguane",
1.9.3p194 :007 >                           :email => "paul.mcguane1@westnet.com.au"
1.9.3p194 :008?>                }
1.9.3p194 :009?>            }
 => {:user=>{:gender=>"male", :last_name=>"paul", :password=>"abc231", :first_name=>"mcguane", :email=>"paul.mcguane1@westnet.com.au"}} 
1.9.3p194 :010 > user = User.new(params[:user])
 => #<User id: nil, postcode: nil, city: nil, state: nil, manager: nil, admin: nil, mobile: nil, team_id: nil, position: nil, gender: "male", dob: nil, email: "paul.mcguane1@westnet.com.au", jersey: nil, last_name: "paul", first_name: "mcguane", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, encrypted_password: "$2a$10$i81k9gX3uYJ95oID.deGyOtDGFSnK6ooI0BIUiP6UtgZ...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: nil, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, provider: nil, uid: nil> 
1.9.3p194 :011 > user.valid?
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'paul.mcguane1@westnet.com.au' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'paul.mcguane1@westnet.com.au' LIMIT 1
 => true 
1.9.3p194 :012 > user.errors.full_messages
 => [] 
1.9.3p194 :013 >
```

rails console with ! method

```
    1.9.3p194 :013 > user.save!
   (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'paul.mcguane1@westnet.com.au' LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'paul.mcguane1@westnet.com.au' LIMIT 1
  SQL (135.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("admin", "city", "created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "dob", "email", "encrypted_password", "first_name", "gender", "jersey", "last_name", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "manager", "mobile", "position", "postcode", "provider", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "state", "team_id", "uid", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["admin", nil], ["city", nil], ["created_at", Wed, 11 Jul 2012 20:05:28 EST +10:00], ["current_sign_in_at", nil], ["current_sign_in_ip", nil], ["dob", nil], ["email", "paul.mcguane1@westnet.com.au"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$i81k9gX3uYJ95oID.deGyOtDGFSnK6ooI0BIUiP6UtgZOuzWzQbFy"], ["first_name", "mcguane"], ["gender", "male"], ["jersey", nil], ["last_name", "paul"], ["last_sign_in_at", nil], ["last_sign_in_ip", nil], ["manager", nil], ["mobile", nil], ["position", nil], ["postcode", nil], ["provider", nil], ["remember_created_at", nil], ["reset_password_sent_at", nil], ["reset_password_token", nil], ["sign_in_count", nil], ["state", nil], ["team_id", nil], ["uid", nil], ["updated_at", Wed, 11 Jul 2012 20:05:28 EST +10:00]]
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => true
```

Comment: Which errors?  I don't see any.

Comment: Is it that your users are not saved at all after the process is finished? Could you post your User model code?

Comment: you are getting rollback transaction, probably because email already exists.

Answer (score 1):

From your code snippet and the log output it seems that your users are not being saved because of some validation problem. 
Usually when I have such a problem I just drop to the rails console and find out
if what my code is trying to do works in the console as well. If it works on the console then your code should work.

Try this

```
$ rails c --sandbox

> params = {
           :user => {
                   :gender => "male",
                :last_name => "paul",
                 :password => "abc231",
               :first_name => "mcguane",
                    :email => "paul.mcguane1@westnet.com.au"
           }
         }

> user = User.new(params[:user])
> user.valid?
> user.errors.full_messages
```

That way, you'd be able to isolate if really User validation is the cause of the problem. It could be something else entirely. If you'd post your User model code would also help.

I also noticed that you are setting a flash notice inside your `lines` iterator. You are simply overwriting it each time you iterate on a line.

Comment: ive uploaded the post with user model, and rails console output

Comment: In that case it could be failing on Devise's validation of your User model since you have the validatable module enabled. try and save the user you've created on the console. Use the save with the bang (user.save!) which will throw an exception if it fails.

Comment: kibyegen it seems to have succeeded with the !

Comment: though if i add to the live app in the controller, i get ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ImportsController#create

SQLite3::BusyException: cannot rollback transaction - SQL statements in progress: rollback transaction`

Comment: Then in that case its because multiple processes are trying to commit to SQLite at the same time which SQLite3 prohibits to protect the integrity of your data. That explains why committing one user in the console works and creating a number of them using an iterator doesn't, seems another process is trying to commit while the lock is still held by another process. Look at the [SQLite FAQ](http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q5). You might consider switching to Postgresql or MySQL.

Comment: fixed the last issue, yet still the users will not save from the import routine :S

Comment: this seems to be an issue i believe with devise now, as ive tested the code with other models, and they all seem to work. its really doing my head now why when the email doesnt exist it states that it does and doesnt import the user

Comment: I had another look at your User model and noticed that you have email validations and you've also turned on Devise's Validatable module. Validatable takes care of email validations for you so that's duplicated. Read the [Devise validatable module docs](http://is.gd/J4LGvA) for more info. I also noted that you have attr_accesible set on :admin which makes it possible to mass assign the admin parameter and this can be exploited by a hacker to make himself an admin. Read [this post](http://stephensclafani.com/2010/01/04/ruby-on-rails-secure-mass-assignment/) on how to guard against such.